# npm-install doesn't install sub-dependencies

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am working on an Angular 4 project. I have created a project that has certain dependencies. The project in itself works fine.

Now I wish to use this project in another project. I added the former project to package.json (under dependencies) of the latter.

Now when I run `npm install`, the package gets installed, but its dependencies are not, and I have to install them manually to get my project working.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening? If there are any errors on my part in implementing this?

Code:

ui-common package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
    "ag-grid": "^17.1.1",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^17.1.0",
    "angular-split": "=0.2.2",
    "angular-tree-component": "^7.0.2-beta1",
    "core-js": "=2.5.1",
    "draggabilly": "^2.2.0", // The one causing trouble
    "foundation-sites": "=6.3.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "x2js": "^3.2.1",
    "zone.js": "=0.8.18"
  }
```

client-app package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/common": "=4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "=4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "=4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "=4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "=4.4.6",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "=4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "=4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "=4.4.6",
    "@goldsam/ng-golden-layout": "0.0.3",
    "@ngui/scrollable": "^0.9.1",
    "@ngui/utils": "^0.8.1",
    "ag-grid": "^16.0.1",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^16.0.0",
    "angular-tree-component": "=7.0.2-beta1",
    "core-js": "=2.5.1",
    "enhanced-resolve": "=3.4.1",
    "foundation-sites": "=6.3.1",
    "golden-layout": "^1.5.9",
    "intl": "=1.2.5",
    "mdn-polyfills": "=5.5.0",
    "morgan": "=1.9.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "=5.5.2",
    "typescript-collections": "1.3.2",
    "ui-common": "1.0.0-beta.25", // package included here
    "zone.js": "=0.8.18"
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us the project structure?

Comment: What are the sub-dependencies? You mean dev dependencies?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried doing npm install --include dependencies. It might also be the fact that you might be running an older version as well so you need to do

```
npm install -v 2.0.0
```

This should install the gem dependencies in the Atom project folder